# Dereferencing ioremap addresses

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, why is it not advisable to dereference the kernel linear addresses obtained by mapping I/O physical addresses using ioremap ? Why should those mapped linear addresses be dereferenced using functions like readl/writel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some architectures require special instructions to be used to access the IO ports, for example to bypass the cache.

Comment: For example, the blackfin arch does not use a simple dereference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackfin http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/arch/blackfin/include/asm/io.h#L29

Comment: Can is use `ioremap` to access PCI I/O memory?

Comment: @caf: but this means the architecture uses port IO not memory mapped IO. ioremap() is used for memory mapped IO.

Comment: @Bandicoot: The "special instructions" are not necessarily the actual data transfer instructions, but instructions that need to surround them for correctness.  Look at the Blackfin implementations linked by sharth in the first comment for an example.

Comment: @IanVaughan it is also used for remapping PCI phy address. (in the book LDD3 pp.226)